# Is there a good way to check for similarity between two words?

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a something that can return a boolean is two word are similar. For example, it would return true if bike and motorcycle are compared. Likewise bus and buses. I looked into spacy but it's percent and I'd have no idea how to properly threshold it. Also some extra context, what I plan on doing is using detectron2 and NLP to automate the I am not a robot thing. However, detectron2 gives bus as a class and the robot thing gives buses- same for bikes and motorcycles

Comment: how would you decide if `bike` is similar to `motorcycle`?

Comment: Sorry about that- how to get the right threshold. I'll edit it right now

Comment: Also @jsotola that's kind of the issue. That's what I need NLP for. Hoping someone knew about something that solves this problem

Comment: perhaps this site may be more useful ... https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It really depends on your granularity. If you say all transportation, then bike, motorcycle, and bus are similar, based on the context we use in NLP. But somehow you can also say that buses and bikes are different transportation tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a threshold is the proper way to do it.
You could determine the best threshold by testing different values and keeping the one that has the best balance between [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).